# Удалить поля в MySQL с условием

Tags: mysql

Добрый день. Необходимо удалить поля (заменить их значения на `NULL`), размер которых меньше 10 символов).

Структура таблицы следующая:

```
-----------------------------------------
Name | City | Phone1 | Phone 2 | Phone 3
-----------------------------------------
```

Знаю, что нужно использовать условие `where CHAR_LENGTH (phone1)<11 ...`, но как составить запрос не могу понять.

Заранее спасибо за совет!

Answer (score 3):

`UPDATE table SET phone1 = NULL WHERE CHAR_LENGTH(phone1) < 11`?

Comment: спасибо, wirtwelt!

Comment: Подскажите, пожалуйста, как удалить последний символ (при условии, что этот символ - пробел) в строке?

Comment: Ну посмотрите строковые функции MySQL, их множество, примеров и информации тоже. Если конкретно последний пробел, то читайте про IF, SUBSTR, LENGTH и комбинируйте. Если просто нужен аналог trim(), то `TRIM(TRAILING ' ' FROM <field> )` ну и куда вам его надо